# How to calculate probability of an event in a stochastic setting?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $\left(\, B_{t}\,\right)_{t\ \geq\ 0}$ be a Brownian motion. Calculate the probability of the event:
$$
E\equiv\left\{\,\exists\ \epsilon > 0 : \forall\ 0 < h < \epsilon,
\max_{t\ \in\ \left[\, 0,h\,\right]}B_{t} >
\left\vert\,\min_{t\ \in\ \left[\, 0,h\,\right]}{B_t}\right\vert\,\right\}
$$

Now, I assume that we can apply reflection principle to calculate supremum of the brownian motion, however, I have no idea how to actually approach the problem. Any advice on how to get to the solution is highly welcome.

Comment: Zero? (Nice problem.)